# Azure Send Push Notification Error

Tags: c#, winforms, azure, push-notification, windows-phone

I was able to send push notifications to my users successfully. But approx. 20 minutes later I did not. Always gives me `TargetInvocationException` error.

I use a notification hub in my `Windows Phone` app. I send notifications from my desktop application by using `FullAccessed` connection string and hub name.

I removed some unnecessary code lines (to understand easily) below.

```
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient
    .CreateClientFromConnectionString(sConStr, sHubName);
string toast = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                    "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                    "<wp:Toast>" +
                    "<wp:Text1>" + txtHeader.Text + "</wp:Text1>" +
                    "<wp:Text2>" + txtContent.Text + "</wp:Text2>" +
                    "</wp:Toast> " +
                    "</wp:Notification>";

    await hub.SendMpnsNativeNotificationAsync(toast);
```

Here is a screenshot.[image]